# Texture across two faces

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to create a diamond shape with a texture. I've created the geometry that I want but now I'm having trouble applying a texture onto the diamond.

It seems to be splitting it on the face and I'm not really sure why. I'm pretty new to three.js, so any help would be great. What's causing this issue and how can I resolve it?

Here's my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7fjLar4b/

```
geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry();
geometry.vertices = [
  new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0),
  new THREE.Vector3(2, 1, 0),
  new THREE.Vector3(1, 2, 0),
  new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0)
];
geometry.faces = [
  new THREE.Face3(1, 2, 3),
  new THREE.Face3(3, 0, 1)
];
texture = loader.load("https://i.imgur.com/am2LQon.jpg")

material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture});
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);
```

Comment: This is how that is normally done: `geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 1, 1, 1, 1 ); geometry.scale( Math.sqrt( 2 ), Math.sqrt( 2 ), 1 ); geometry.rotateZ( - Math.PI / 4 ); geometry.translate( 1, 1, 0 );` ... Or, create a custom `THREE.Geometry` from scratch. But do not assign new vertices/faces to `THREE.PlaneGeometry`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order of vertices for the first face

```
geometry.faces = [
  new THREE.Face3(2, 3, 1),
  new THREE.Face3(3, 0, 1)
];
```